# Concept - Does a queue have direction?

Tags: javascript

I called it a queue but according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28data_structure%29) a queue is a first in first out data structure.

You add to the "front".  And you remove from the "end".

I'm doing the opposite.

I'm adding to the "end".  And removing from the "front".  ( using push() and shift() )

Because front and end don't have any concrete meaning does direction even matter?

I'm just going off examples from wikipedia and [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Can I call it a queue?

Comment: Sure you can. However, does that question really fit SO?

Comment: You must have misread, for a queue elements are added to the *back* and removed from the *front*

Comment: "Front" and "End" are just names. What you have is a stack. Last item added is the first item removed.

Comment: Yes, but it's just a matter of semantics. If he's adding to one end and removing from the other, it's a queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I call it a queue?

**Absolutely**. The definition you cite is correct; a queue is "FIFO", first in first out. That does *not* necessarily mean that you have to use one end of the array or the other. In fact, you don't even need an array. You could just as well use a linked list to represent a queue.

Comment: It is an abstract data type - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28data_structure%29, the title is wrong.

Comment: ... just thinking out loud, but I think is important to differentiate between abstract data types and data structures ... the two are often blurred together... perfect example is the link I just posted.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the variable names "front" to "end" and "end" to "front" does not change the data structure or algorithm you are using.  It's still a queue.

And that's all you're doing.  It doesn't really matter if you choose to think of the roles of the "front" and "end" reversed.  When you get in line at a teller you enter the "end" and wait until you're at the "front."  That is a queue.

Answer (score 1):

I have always heard Queues semantically described as enqueued items added to the back/tail and dequeued items removed from the front/head.

What I described above is consistent with the Wikipedia article you linked to. I am not sure where you picked up the opposite semantics.

**The computer won't care what you name your variables. However, I suggest that you stick to the convention described in my opening sentence to be consistent with common practice.**

I also suggest that you remove the `pop` invocation from your code (use shift instead) to avoid confusion.